# ChromeDriver under FreeBSD

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, freebsd

With FreeBSD-7.3 amd64 and Python 2.6 I cannot make it possible to run ChromeDriver. ChromeDriver binary is added to path and Chrome works fine in appropriate display but I keep getting errors related to binary incompatibility or something similar *ELF binary type "0" not known.*:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> d = webdriver.Chrome()
ELF binary type "0" not known.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 60, in __init__
self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.py", line 58, in start
and read up at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path.                 Please download from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list                and read up at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver'
>>>
```

The same when I am trying to execute binary: *ELF binary type "0" not known.*
I've tried both with chromedriver_linux64_19.0.1068.0.zip and 18 version with no luck. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

This is a Linux binary. To run that under FreeBSD you need to install at least the Linux emulator base port, `/usr/ports/emulators/linux_base-f10`. And probably the Linux versiond of a host of other libraries.

The Chromium browser is available as a native FreeBSD binary with the port `/usr/ports/www/chromium`. But this doesn't build the chromedriver by default. You could ask the port maintainer to add it? Or build it, go into the work directory and use `gmake chromedriver`. If that works, put the binary somewhere in your path.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver` is installed by default now when you install chromium by ports (`www/chromium)`